# Can the union of lines be an area?

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Edit: How come when we measure the area using integrals we get a 'nice' answer, but when we sum up the value ("height") of every positive continuous function on an interval $[a,b]$ the sum: $\Sigma U$ when $U=\{f(x)\mid x\in[a,b[\}$ divergs. Why doesn't the second sum describe the are under the graph? Sorry for the long phrasing below.
$$$$
It is known that the sum of any uncountable set $U$ of positive numbers diverges $\Sigma U=\infty$. Because of that, if we try to calculate the area under a continuous graph like $f(x)=x$ at $[0,1]$ the "area" diverges. On the other hand, Riemann sums are working because they are defined by taking the limit of a natural number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ to infinity. I wonder what is the reason that the former method doesn't work. An intuitive definition for area is that the points of a set $A$ are "an area" iff: $$\forall a_0\ \forall \epsilon>0\  \exists a\in A \ \ s.t\mid a_0 - a\mid <\epsilon$$
So I tried to use this definition to prove that any set of lines can't form an area, but it seems false for uncountable sets. What is the real reason we can't calculate area using sum of 1-D lines?

Comment: Why the area under $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ diverges? Do youe mean the area of the set $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y\leq x, x\in [0,1]\}$?

Comment: Can you explain how your definition relates to area? What set is $a_0$ in? If you're trying to say that there's always two points in $A$ arbitrarily close together, two issues: (1) We can let $a=a_0$, which is a point that certainly has $0$ area. (2) A line has $0$ area despite satisfying this condition. You might be interested in the topological concept of an *interior.*

Comment: edited to clarify. I'll read about interior but can you explain briefly if and how this concept is treated in calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the area of a line is 0 so it's not positive, so the sum of the area even of uncountable many lines is 0
2. in measure theory, it is false that an uncountable sum of the area of disjointed sets is the area of the union of the sets (area is the measure here). It's just not in the axiom of the measure.
3. what you are defining as an "area" is a dense set, you can look up the definition of a dense subset of a metric space.
4. a dense set doesn't necessarly have an area, for exemple $\mathbb{Q}^2\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ has measure (or area) 0 and is dense.

Comment: I edited the question, does the first point still apply? I want to understand why 
"summing up the heights" method doesn't work because that is what we do with Riemann sums but with a sum on a countable set. And does point 2 apply for calculus as well? I learned this in the context of integrals and would like to understand using the tools I have if possible.

Comment: Yes, first point still apply. In riemann integral, you make rectangle which have area, while when you sum the "heights" of a function, if i understand correctly, you are summing lines which have an area of 0. Point 2 is purely about measure theory since i'm talking about area, not sure how you would apply it to calculus. If you look up the axioms of a measure, which is the function that define what area is, the countable additivity axiom is what imply point 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider, for each $\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$, the line given by
$$\ell_\theta (t)= t(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$$.

The union of that lines is $\mathbb{R}^2$